# Why is the rigidbody not animating with the character?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

basically, I am making a walking animation and i already made the rigid body drop and rest on the neck of my character in t-pose, now when i try to play the walk animation the whole necklace just scatter away

more detail.
rigidbody settings

[image]

[image]

rigidbody only works when i turned off the alembic baked animation
[image]

don't know if the problem is due to the baked animation from marvelous designer, as long as i play it the rigidbody doesn't collide with it and if I check the animated checkbox it just explodes .

Comment: how shall we help you if you just some pictures without any useful information what you made and what settings you used? Since you seem to be a beginner - providing your blend file is a good idea

Comment: my bad, this is my first post and i didn't  see  a way to post my blend files with the images, here is a link to the blend file.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rU30f_nPir4G7rB27IPeIN6I42RHtvU2/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @Damilola It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: please do file -> external data -> pack resources before saving and uploading to cloud so that we really see what you did, thx

Comment: hello guys, i packed the files already but here is another try, file path made absolute and packed into blend https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rU30f_nPir4G7rB27IPeIN6I42RHtvU2/view?usp=sharing